# Keras - test and training loss/accuracy overlap

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have developed parameters for a Keras model and looked at the loss and accuracy over epochs as shown below. What does it mean when your loss and accuracy overlaps for test and training data? What else is apparent from the data in these graphs? This is a classification supervised learning model.

[image: Accuracy and Loss over epochs]

Comment: It is actually good when the gap between the test error and training error is low. That means your model is not over-fitting. In other words, your model is well generalized.

Comment: What is the loss function? And what is the unit of the loss in the second graph? Is it the sum of losses over all samples?

Comment: you can't really see if the losses are overlapping due to the different scales. Scale your y axis logarithimically to be able to see big and small values in the same plot. Alternatively you can plot the data starting with epoch 20 or so.